# Increasing math mode font size in tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize

Consider the following simple tikz picture

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikz \draw (1,0) node{$\pi$} circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I want to scale (increase the size) of the pi, but not of the circle itself.

I already tried to use a scalebox, but the resulting text wasn't placed inside the circle. I also tried

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikz \draw (1,0) node{\large $\pi$} circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikz \draw (1,0) node[font=\large]{$\pi$} circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but both result in the error "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]."

Can you tell me if there is a way to properly increase the font size for math mode inside tikz pictures?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `scale`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (1,0) node[scale=6]{$\pi$} circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or use `font=\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont` with `lmodern` loaded.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (1,0) node[font=\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont]{$\pi$} circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

BTW `\tikz \draw` should be `\draw` inside `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: thank you for both, the answer to my font size problem and the answer to the problem with the input stack size error (which was to remove the \tikz)!