# TikZ: How can text in a node be increased?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, fontsize, tikz-styles

I'd like to draw some circles with text inside. I can increase the radius, but the text naturally always stays the same. I know `\Huge`, which I tried to use, but it seems not to work in math-mode. How can the textsize of `T_1` to `T_4` below be controlled/increased?

MCVE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,line cap=round,line 
join=round,scale=2]

  \coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
  \draw ($(A)+(0,2,4)$) circle [radius=2] node {$T_1$};
  \draw ($(A)+(0,-0.5,4)$) circle [radius=2] node {$T_2$};
  \draw ($(A)+(0,-2,4)$) circle [radius=2] node {$T_3$};
  \draw ($(A)+(0,0,2)$) circle [radius=2] node {${\Huge T_4}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably related? [Increasing math mode font size in tikz picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215809/134144)

Comment: `\Huge` needs to be outside the math mode (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/490070). E.g. `\documentclass{article} \begin{document}  $a$ or $\Huge a$ or {\Huge $a$}.\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help! I really apprechiate it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the node option `font`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,line cap=round,line 
join=round,scale=2]

  \coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
  \draw ($(A)+(0,2,4)$) circle [radius=2] node[font=\Huge] {$T_1$};
  \draw ($(A)+(0,-0.5,4)$) circle [radius=2] node[font=\Huge] {$T_2$};
  \draw ($(A)+(0,-2,4)$) circle [radius=2] node[font=\Huge] {$T_3$};
  \draw ($(A)+(0,0,2)$) circle [radius=2] node[font=\Huge] {$T_4$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your node should be all with `font=\Huge`, you can put this option as parameter of your `tikzpicture` environment.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,line cap=round,line 
join=round,scale=2, font=\Huge]

  \coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
  \draw ($(A)+(0,2,4)$) circle [radius=2] node {$T_1$};
  \draw ($(A)+(0,-0.5,4)$) circle [radius=2] node {$T_2$};
  \draw ($(A)+(0,-2,4)$) circle [radius=2] node {$T_3$};
  \draw ($(A)+(0,0,2)$) circle [radius=2] node {$T_4$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I think also the `scale` solution @leandriis posted in the comment above will work.

Comment: @avermaet Thank you! Of course, `scale` works, I used `font` because you mention `\Huge` in your question.